# How do I code MXML to attach a listener to a custom ActionScript class

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, event-handling

For example, the following MXML script attaches a listener to a Button class:

```
<mx:Button id="STACK" label="OVERFLOW" click="doStuff()"/>
```

I have a custom action script class which fires an event when a value is updated and I wish to be able to listen for that event in an MXML class:

ActionScript Class:

```
public function set currentPage(newCurrentPage: Number) : void {
    _currentPage = newCurrentPage;

    dispatchEvent(new DataEvent(PAGE_CHANGED, true, false, _currentPage));
}
```

And I wish to be able to do the following in MXML:

```
<myClass:Class <...> pageChanged="doMoreStuff()" />
```

How would I do this?  Cheers :)

Comment: What is the type of your class `myClass`?

Comment: I suppose it would need to extend Canvas to be able to be displayed.  In reality this is an 'abstract' class which is extended by other components.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to declare the event with a metadata tag:

```
<mx:Metadata>
[Event(name="pageChanged", type="full.type.name.of.DataEvent")]
</mx:Metadata>
```

The name of the event must match the event name (PAGE_CHANGED constant in your example).

Edit: if you're writing the class in ActionScript instead of MXML, you can apply the metadata tag directly to your class:

```
[Event(name="pageChanged", type="full.type.name.of.DataEvent")]
public class MyClass extends WhateverItExtends
```